# Кредиты и вклады

Tags: python, время

Мне нужно сделать сделать автоматизированную систему проверки кода. То-есть:
В каждое утро в 10 часов выполнялась функция. Если код не был запущен, то после запуска он выдал и продолжил счет времени.
Пример кода:

```
import datetime
current_datetime = datetime.now()
while True:
     if current_datetime == "2019-12-13 12:18:19.290623":
         print("true")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть множество способов реализации данной программы

Я укажу наверное самый простой:

Две программы - бот и вспомогательный сервис:

Бот:

> Если человек берет кредит:

```
Записываем информацию в базу данных о том, что человек взял кредит
```

> Если человек выплачивает кредит:

```
Записываем информацию в базу данных о том, что человек выплатил кредит
```

Сервис:

Каждый день запускается в определенное время и проверяет выплатили ли кредит люди, если нет, то добавляет информацию о том, что кредит был увеличен на 5%. В случае, если это 10я строчка, то выполняем некий def

Дальше от этого можете придумывать другие таблицы для более удобного и структурирования хранения информации. Этого минимума хватит, чтобы отслеживать кредит и кредитную историю пользователя

Comment: Я считаю stackoverflow все-таки сайтом для советов или помощи с уже имеющимся кодом(исправить/дополнить/понять). Всю систему можно прописать только в исключительно сложных случаях

Comment: 3й пункт о том, какие вопросы не стоит задавать. Я попытался ответить на вопрос, максимально подталкивая Вас. Нужно лишь немного разобраться в том, что Вы делаете:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

На самом деле задача не такая уж и сложная и каждый может её реализовать при желании

Comment: Домашние задания здесь как самый частый пример. Суть в том, что здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — **моветон**

Comment: я обратился, так как даже начать систему я не могу. я не понимаю как ее начать